# Structure of Positive Ordered Monoids

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $(M,+,0)$ be a positive totally ordered commutative monoid, i.e. a commutative monoid with a total order relation $\leq$ satisfying

- $a\leq b \Rightarrow a+c\leq b+c$ for all $c\in M$.
- $0\leq a$ for all $a\in M$.

I want to know how to classify them and under which conditions we can classify them more or less easily. I'm specially interested when they are finitely generated.

For example with just that we can have some weird monoids with idempotents ($M=\{0,1\}$ with $0+1=1+1=1,0+0=0$, $0\leq 1$). But what if we add the condition for $M$ to be cancellative? Then we have no idempotents, and we have some submonoids isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$ ($\{a,2a,3a,\dots\}$ for $a\in M-\{0\}$). It looks like in this case $M$ wants to be a submonoid or quotient of $\mathbb{N}^n$ for some $n$ (if it is finitely generated).

What can we find out about the structure of $M$ in this case?

Comment: Every cancellative commutative monoid $X$ canonically embeds in a group $\mathsf{GG}(X)$ via the [Grothendieck group construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid#Grothendieck_group_construction). This gives us an equivalence relation on cancellative positive ordered commutative monoids, namely $M\sim N$ iff $\mathsf{GG}(M)\cong \mathsf{GG}(X)$. This is a strictly coarser relation than isomorphism - for example, consider the submonoids $\mathbb{N}_{\ge 0}$ and $\mathbb{N}_{\ge 0}\setminus\{1,2,4,5\}$ (not a typo!) of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: So the classification problem for cancellative positive ordered commutative monoids breaks into two pieces: $(i)$ classify ordered abelian groups, and $(ii)$ for each ordered abelian group $G$, classify the set $\mathsf{PM}(G)$ of cancellative positive ordered commutative monoids $M$ with $\mathsf{GG}(M)\cong G$. In the finitely generated case, $(i)$ has a relatively snappy answer: the finitely generated orderable abelian groups are exactly the groups isomorphic to some finite power of $\mathbb{Z}$ - so *(if we ignore the ordering)* it will be enough to understand submonoids of $\mathbb{N}^n$.